# protractor tests throwing 'InvalidElementStateError: SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12' on safari

Tags: angularjs, selenium, safari, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Details:

I'm trying to run a set of ui tests against safari using protractor. Our App is running on angular. Every single test fails at startup with the error 'InvalidElementStateError: SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12'. Can't seem to find any information on this issue elsewhere.

Version of Safari installed: Version 7.0.5 (9537.77.4)

Comment: What kind of selectors against what kind of HTML?

Comment: className selectors, for example 'app-uploads-drop-text', html5

Comment: We can't help you if you don't share any code ;)